# 2011 Ford Fusion bounces on bumps..no leak dealer wont replace struts even though still in warranty

Tags: suspension

Brought my car 2011 Ford Fusion 4 cyl SEL to the dealer before the 36,000 mile warranty expires because in my opinion the car bounces, it does not absorb the bumps although no problem on the highway. Bought this car used at 28,000 miles from the dealer and filed a complaint one month later about this issue however the service person said there was nothing wrong. Carfax shows this was a rental vehicle prior to my purchase so I am assuming the vehicle must've gone through abuse and that is why I feel the bouncing around at 35,000 miles but the dealer will not agree to replace the struts. I can see he is trying to have me pay for it once it reaches 36,000 miles... I am sure of that. What else can I do to bypass this dealer and get this thing taken care of. I have a case number with Ford and I'm trying to do this in the proper manner. Why should I be driving with an inferior product while still under warranty. Do I have any legal recourse such as "lemon law" or similar? Can anyone suggest how to approach this issue. Thank you for any suggestions.

George

Comment: What do you mean by “bouncing”?

Answer (score 3):

If you really believe there's something noticeably wrong, ask the dealer if you can test drive an identical vehicle with a technician in the car with you. Then drive your car the same route at the same speeds with the same technician. If there's truly a noticeable difference, he'll be more inclined to admit it.

Otherwise, it's a very subjective thing to measure without a full suspension testing center.